# Start jQuery UI Slider From 10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I would like to start my jQuery UI slider from 10 and I had set the min value as 10, but it starts from zero.

My code is

```
_app.detailsDivInit = function() {
        debugger;
        $( ".slider" ).slider({
        min: 10,
        max: 60,
        step: 1
    })
    .each(function() {
        var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;
        debugger;
        //Get the number of possible values
        var vals = opt.max - opt.min;

      // Space out values
      for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i+=opt.step * 20) {
        debugger;
        var el = $('<label>'+(i + "-" + (i + opt.step*20) )+' <div class="tickMark"></div></label>').css('left',(i/vals*100)+'%');
        $( ".slider" ).append(el);
      } 
    });
```

I gave the value as 10 but it still starts from zero, and I don't know why.

Comment: can you please check this fiddle link "http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/uv5aC/" i hope this will help you at some level to solve your problem

Comment: @Lalitpatadiya :no page exist

Comment: just copy between ",,," value page their

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/uv5aC/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about what you are trying to do with the ranges though (there's only 50 units with a min of 10 and a max of 60, so you can't actually divide it into 3 20 sized blocks). Anyhow, see if the below is closer to what you are looking for - just replace your for block with the below.

```
for (var i = opt.min; i <= vals; i+=opt.step * 20) {
    debugger;
    var el = $('<label>'+(i + "-" + Math.min(i + opt.step*20, opt.max))+' <div class="tickMark"></div></label>').css('left',((i - opt.min)/vals*100)+'%');
    $( ".slider" ).append(el);
}
```